# Problem with figures captions

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

### Hello, it's me again :D

I have problem with figures captions.

### [image]

I'd like to make my two figures nearby and the captions so that they do not overlap. But it all fell apart.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{mwrep}
\linespread{1,3}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=centerlast]{caption}\usepackage{floatrow}



\begin{document}[h]
\begin{figure}

\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
\caption{Text}\label{...}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It should be

  ```
  \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  \begin{document}[h]
  \begin{figure}
  ```
- It should be

  ```
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Text}\label{...}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{2}}
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  \caption{Text}\label{...}

  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{2}
  ```

  Notice the extra set of brackets `{}` around `caption` and `includegraphics`

Comment: +1, however for float placement is better to use `[ht]` than `[h]` :-)

Comment: @Zarko I agree =) However, the author used `h` so I kept his original version (even if I personally disagree)